# Fix the following arguments are required: --input-dir, --output-dir''

Tags: python

i have install all the modules for deepfacelive but when i try to run deepfacelive it says '' the following arguments are required: --input-dir, --output-dir''.  how can I fix the error message on my anaconda prompt

this is the command i used to run deepfacelive. python main.py extract DeepFaceLive -- user data-dir C:\Users\Steps\Documents\DeepFaceLab-master

Answer (score 1):

The diagnostic message is explaining that you need to add `--input-dir my_input`
and `--output-dir my_output` arguments when you execute the command.
Use `mkdir` to create those directories, and then re-run.